# How to select in daterangepicker only year in Yii2?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, yii2, daterangepicker

I need help with the boostrap daterangepicker in YII 2. I need to change select range only in year format. I am using https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-date-range

I need to select date 2000-2005, 1990-2000 .... only year without month and date. I found this option only in the base bootstrap datepicker.

Comment: disabling the view of date and month depends on the options provided by bootstrap.. as far as i know there is no option like that. you might wants to use any alternative like either use the simple dropdown like diffrent projects use for year selection.

Answer (score 2):

What have you tried to implement until now so that we can help you more and add some code in your question which will also help.

I would suggest you to try `clientoption` and try disabling month and date view
and go to that website of kartik where docs are available and read the options at top,as its a third party tool than it might have limitations and might be explained more on the official site of the widget

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [documentation](http://www.daterangepicker.com/) for the plugin the [Kartik widget](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-date-range) is based on doing what you want doesn't seem to be possible, but Yii2 already has this functionality [built in](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-jui-datepicker.html):

1, Add this css to hide everything on the calendar widget except the year

```
<style type="text/css">
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

2, Use the built in Yii widget, change class/model names to reflect your actual project

```
echo $form->field($model, 'time_scheduled')->widget(\yii\jui\DatePicker::classname(), [

    'clientOptions' => [

        'changeMonth' => false,
        'changeYear' => true,
        'showButtonPanel' => true,
        'dateFormat' => 'yyyy',
        'yearRange' => '1990:2020'
    ],
]);
```

3, In testing this I found I had to add this javascript too (but there might be a better way)

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.ui-datepicker-close', function (e) {
    var value = $('.ui-datepicker-year :selected').text();
    $('#feed-time_scheduled').val(value);
});
```

Yii is using the bootstrap datepicker and the opions for that are [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-jui-datepicker.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
echo DatePicker::widget([
'model' => $model,
'attribute' => 'start_date',
'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Start date'],
'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_COMPONENT_PREPEND,
'form' => $form,
'pluginOptions' => [
'format' => 'mm/yyyy',
'autoclose' => true,
'minViewMode' => 1,
]
]);
```